# with vboxmanage, how to list all snapshots of vm?

Tags: virtualbox

With virtualbox (On windows 7 host), how can I list all the snapshots of a VM?

Ideally, there will be one line per snapshot, and each snapshot will have the name and the UUID.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this

```
vboxmanage snapshot VM_NAME list
```

You can also specify the output format by including the option `--machinereadable`

All commands of vboxmanage can be found by

```
vboxmanage --help
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not the best answer I want, but `vboxmanage showvminfo VMNAME` will list the snapshots at the end of it's output.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the right answer. If you want to filter the ouput from showvminfo, you'll need to do it from the shell via command line